# Flutter/Dart overwriting File in getApplicationDocumentsDirectory not working immediately

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to overwrite a file in my apps temporary directory but for some reason the overwrite is not taking effect until I fully hot restart my app.

I'm trying to set my _pickedImage variable to the new changedImage once it has been copied to the directory, however when using setState it is always keeping the first image that was placed into the directory and not overwriting it each time. So when I display the _pickedImage it will always show the first initial image until i fully restart, once i fully restart the app the change is taking place. The reason for wanting to do this is so that users can effectively change the image if they wish. Hope this makes sense any help would be massively appreciated

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 800.0);

if (image != null) {

  final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/image';

  if (Directory(dirPath).existsSync()) {
    print('it exists');
    var dir = new Directory(dirPath);
    dir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    if (Directory(dirPath).existsSync()) {
      print('still exists');
    } else {
      //It is getting in here so seemingly its deleting the orignal directory
      print('does not exist');
    }
  }

  new Directory(dirPath).createSync(recursive: true);
  String path =
      '$dirPath/temporaryImage.jpg';

  File changedImage = image.copySync(path);`


    setState(() {
      //this is where the problem lies
      _pickedImage = changedImage;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Cache is the problem. See issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24858

From documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html

> ImageProvider uses the global imageCache to cache images.

You can use

```
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart'

// to clear specific cache
imageCache.evict(FileImage(processedImage));

// to clear all cache
imageCache.clear();
```

It did not directly solve issue I had, however, it was the key.